# Want to scrape data from a url, but im getting an error, i'm using python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, database, web-scraping, finance

i've encountered this error when trying to scrape a web page:

> 

```
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.759 seconds
```

anyone can tell me how to solve this? my code as below:

> 

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.xpi.com.br/investimentos/fundos-de-investimento/lista/#/"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
lists = soup.find_all('section', class_="xp-flex-body")

for list in lists:
    title = lists.find('div', class_="onclick-fund")
    type = lists.find('p', class_="xp__text xp__text--small")
    info = [title, type]
    print(info)
```

Important to say that i've got NO coding background. I work in finance and my boss asked me to get the data from this web page and convert it to xls (name of the fund and type). Its been a day since i'm studying webscraping and the source is mainly youtube.

Thank you in advance! Have a good one.

I'm following the steps of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvCBzhhydNk

When i asked it to print i've tought i would get the data or any specific error, but im just getting "

```
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.759 seconds
```

and don't know what to do.

Thank you.

Comment: If `lists` is empty, you will not get any output. From what I can see the `<section>` is added dynamically after page-load, it does not exists when you GET the URL.

Comment: As @ivvija has said, the content is generated dynamically in the browser. You need to use something like [Selenium WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/) to render the content locally, and then scrape it.

Comment: Thank you, @ivvija and @tromgy!! Gonna try with selenium!

Comment: FYI "exited with code=0" usually means there is no error, as in no Exception was raised by your program, as in it completed running. A _non-zero_ exit code/status is the one with runtime errors, such as calling a non-existent function (`requests.getttt(url)`). Now, for the case where your code's logic is wrong, that could still result in a zero exit code, but it's just that it didn't produce your expected output. Python cannot know that your logic is wrong.